# Outlook Mail REST API v2.0 OData URL capabilities

Tags: office-js, office365api, outlook-restapi

Does Outlook Mail REST API support OData URL capabilities like `$value` ?

I'm able to get the MIME content of an email using:

```
GET https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/messages/{message_id}/$value
```

But I couldn't find any documentation for this feature, all I could find was a documentation for Graph API:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters#other-odata-url-capabilities

and

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-get-mime-message

But nothing for REST API v2.0. I just want to confirm if this is a feature which isn't documented or its just something which is not here to stay for long and might get deprecated somewhere down the road without any general public notice.

Comment: Is this issue specific to outlook web add-ins or is this a general question about Graph / REST APIs?

Comment: General question about the REST APIs supporting `$value` in the get message REST API. I'm trying to use this API in an addin but not sure if this `$value` is supported out of the box with no documentation

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I'm going to remove the outlook-web-addins tag as that tag is specifically for add-ins. The outlook-restapi tag should be sufficient to get the right folks to address your question.